# MongoDB Queries Async for loop results coming back empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, npm

I have a list of IDs to query Mongo with which I am doing in a for loop and it always returns an empty []. Initially it kept returning promises so I moved from `forEach` to the standard for loop as you see here and `toArray()` both of which resulted in an empty [].

```
async function queryRoles(id) {
    const db = await connectToMongo()
    let response;
    try {
        response = await db.collection("permissions").find({"_id": xxx}).toArray();
        console.log(await response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    return response;
}

async function checkAuthorisation(list, groups) {
    for (const item of list) {
        const index = list.indexOf(item);
        const rolesList = await queryRoles(item._id);
        console.log(rolesList);
    };
    }
```

The rolesList always comes back in [] and is never populated with anything.

However, if I just update code with the same query for a single mongo document without using the for loop, the expected response comes back, so I know the connectivity to MongoDB is fine.

What am I doing wrong? Pulling my hair out at this point!!

Comment: Can you wrap await statement like this: `response = (await db.collection("permissions").find({"_id": xxx})).toArray();`

Comment: Yeah, that didn't make any difference.

Comment: please first convert string id into ObjectId.

Comment: you can convert string into object id using 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(string);

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this approach,

```js
  async function checkAuthorisation(list, groups) {
    const roleList = await Promise.all(
      list.map(async (item, index) => 
        await queryRoles(item._id)
      )
    );
    ...
  }
```